# django wysiyg editor image control

Tags: django

Is there a django wysiyg editor I can control its image?

I want to set a default image size and use the image as a thumbnail as well.

all wysiyg contents are represent like `{{content}}` since in model it's set like

```
content=some Wysiyg field()
```

The one I want to do is `{{content.image}}` and play around with that image.

Is there any way I can do that? right now [this](https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor) is the one I'm using,  but I'm willing to change to the one I can control image with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try django-ckeditor, redactor it's more simple but redactor itself isn't free and i think ckeditor is more flexible in the configuration

Comment: do you know how I can achieve the above functionality with ckeditor?

Comment: I found this https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/249, apparently you have to control the size of the image in the server configuration, and to use the thumbnails you need pillow, you can check more in the readme.rst https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor